# mysql.connector multiple queries: Error -1: No result set to fetch from

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

In Python 2.7.3, Wins 10, MySQL remote server 5.6.23, MySQL.connector 2.1.3,

If I wanna run these two queries together in Python MySQL.connector:

```
SELECT * FROM A LIMIT 5;


SELECT DISTINCT COLUM_A FROM B;
```

I got the following error message using the code below:

```
Error -1: No result set to fetch from.
```

Here is the code:

```
import mysql.connector as MySQL

cursor = conn.cursor ()

sql1 = "SELECT * FROM A LIMIT 5;SELECT DISTINCT COLUM_A FROM B"

cursor.execute(sql1,multi=True)

row = cursor.fetchall ()

warning = cursor.fetchwarnings()

print row

print warning

cursor.close ()

conn.close ()
```

Here is the MySQL cursor.execute() official document, which completely confuses me.  Could any guru enlighten?  Thanks!

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to-

```
iterable = cursor.execute(sql1,multi=True)
for item in iterable:
    print(item.fetchall())
```

Should work.